# How do you delete a Signing Certificate in Xcode?

Tags: ios, xcode

When I go to Xcode > Preferences > Accounts and then click on Manage Certificates for my selected Apple ID, I see my list of Signing Certificates.  I tried to delete the certificate from the UI but the delete option is grayed out.  I then found another Stack Overflow page that said to remove certificates from Keychain Access.  I found it and removed it.  However, when I go back to Xcode to the same place as before the Signing Certificate is still there and the option to delete it is still grayed out (see image below).  I don't get it.  Why is it so hard to just let me delete my certificate?

[image]

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It's not enough to delete it from your keychain, the certificate is still present in Apple Developer Center at this point.

**To remove it completely do the following:**

- Log in to Apple Developer Center
- Find the certificate in question and click it
- Now click the "Revoke" button (see attached screenshot). Certificate should disappear.
- Go back to Xcode and refresh the dialog. Now it should be gone.

If it's not gone after you have done this, it just means it's still present in your keychain locally, so just remove it from here as well and you should be good.

[image]

Comment: I don't have any certificates to revoke.  I created the certificates in XCode without a paid apple developer account.  I have since purchased a paid developer account and there aren't any certificates to revoke.

Comment: Sounds very strange. Have you tried removing your developer ID from Xcode and logging in again? @noctufaber

Comment: Yes, I tried that. Unfortunately that didn't work.  :-(

Comment: I have a free Apple developer account. By mistake, I generated a second Signing Certificate using Xcode 10.1. It seems that I cannot delete (revoke) this one through Xcode. Also, the developer.apple.com page doesn't seem to feature an option to manage (not even to view) the Signing Certificates. Do I need to have a paid developer account in order to delete this Signing Certificate?

Comment: There is no such thing as a free Apple developer account. You simply have an Apple ID. To get access to the Apple Developer Center you need to become a developer by signing up and paying the annual fee. After you have doen this you'll be able to manage all your certs. @geohei

Comment: Sorry for the wrong phraseology. Please confirm that when paying for the account, this grants me access to the features to delete/revoke a Signing Certificate? @ØyvindHauge

Comment: I confirm. @geohei

Comment: I ran into the same issue. It really sounds strange, that we can only revoke untapped certs auto-created by Xcode, which will be show in Xcode's "Manage Certificates" window, when we enrol to the Developer Program and thus get access to the cert.

Comment: You don't have to purchase a Developer ID cert to develop Mac or iPhone apps. I have a free Mac Developer cert from Apple that allows me to develop and run locally. When you are ready to deploy to the store or sell outside the store then you'll need to buy the paid cert, i.e., the Developer ID cert, or, if you want access to more developer resources like videos, etc.. You can still manage certs through a combination of your login at apple developer account, your keychain, and Xcode prefs.

Comment: @geohei: How did you solve it, I have a similar problem.

Comment: @oyvindhauge: Can you give me a hand?

Comment: What problem are you facing? @Paul

Comment: @oyvindhauge, This: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73438041/xcode-free-provisioning-remove-certificates

Comment: @oyvindhauge: Can you give me a hand?

Answer (score 9):

I finally deleted the Certificates in XCode.

1. Delete every item you think is related to certificates in *Keychain Access > Keys*. It will look like 'blank keys'
2. Back to *XCode Preferences > Accounts > Manage Certificates* you should see those unwanted certificates showing (x) marks.
3. Restart computer

Comment: Restarting Xcode (and not my computer) was enough in my experience.

Comment: And how to remove certificate with (x) mark from signing certificates list?

Answer (score 1):

To remove a certificate that appear as "Not in Keychain" in XCode, I have found the following works.

1. Revoke the certificate in the Apple Developer Portal (as per previous answer).
2. Remove any provisioning profiles that reference the (removed) certificate.

Comment: Where is the Apple Developer Portal located?

Comment: https://appstoreconnect.apple.com/

Comment: But I don't have a certificate, I use Free Provisioning.

Comment: Doesn't let me log in gives me an error.

Answer (score 0):

You can't really delete a certificate, apparently. You can browse them in "[Certificates, Identifiers & Profiles](https://developer.apple.com/account/mac/certificate/)" inside of your developer account portal, but as far as I can tell, they'll remain there until they expire, and then they'll disappear automatically.

Comment: Not true. If you revoke them manually, they'll be removed immediately (and all related provisioning profiles will be invalidated).

Comment: @noctufaber see my answer

Comment: You may not even be able to "browse" these certs, except in Xcode's "Manage Certificates" window. If you just create one with Xcode they do not automatically appear in the Developer portal of the team where you are a member of where you might revoke them. If you delete the cert and the private key in the Keychain, the entry remains disabled and you cannot revoke them, too.

Answer (score 0):

In case it helps anyone:
I revoked also (deleted) a certificate in App Developer account.
Then I thought I had deleted the certificate too in Keychain access but kept getting error messages, when trying to upload an app update to the AppStore.

I then found out that there are two separate places in keychain access, where in one the certificate is kept (funny enough under keys, once login is selected in keychains) and in the other one the private key (of course under the item certificates in keychains). I made sure that both are deleted and now all is good.